# How do I keep from breaking charcoal pencil leads when I sharpen them with a knife?

Tags: drawing, charcoal, sharpening

I'm fairly good at sharpening graphite pencils with a knife using the technique in the answer in [What is the proper way to sharpen a pencil?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/457/what-is-the-proper-way-to-sharpen-a-pencil)

But I'm always breaking the points when I try to sharpen charcoal pencils.

How do I expose the charcoal from the wood when sharpening with a knife without breaking it?

What techniques can I use to sharpen charcoal pencils without breaking the points?

Comment: Do you get the same problem when you use a fresh blade? How much of the tip is breaking off? (A simple diagram of picture would really help)

Comment: @CreationEdge the points break where the point meets the wood.

Answer (score 3):

Sandpaper.

Really, IMHO the best way to sharpen charcoal pencils is by using sandpaper (100 grit). Works really, really well and the result is perfect.

I start by just rough-shaping it slowly and with a lot of caution with a good sharpener. I usually keep a very small layer of wood over the tip and then move the pencil over the sandpaper which I place on a blanket on my desk. I remove the last little bit of wood like that.

This is demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df6L-2sB9Ow

Comment: How to release the point from the wood when sharpening with a knife without breaking it?

Comment: Well, I am just doing it slowly and with a lot of caution with a good sharpener. And I usually keep a very small layer of wood over the tip and then move the pencil over the sandpaper which I place on a blanket on my desk. And remove the last little bit of wood like that.

Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df6L-2sB9Ow

Comment: @kevin - you would expose the charcoal amount you want shaving off the outer wood with the knife, then shape the point how you like with the sand paper.